# How to Web Deploy Asp.Net Core 2.0 to apache Web server on Ubuntu 17.10.1 from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, apache, ubuntu, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to configure the publish from Visual Studio 2017 to be able to publish my Asp.Net Core 2.0 web site to my Ubuntu 17.10.1 server running Apache.

Most of my googling explains how to copy the compiled code using SSH or such to the Ubuntu machine or even copy the code over and then use `dotnet publish`, but I found this does too any steps for a single deployment.

Does someone out there know how can I use/configure `Publish...`from Visual Studio to deploy my site on my Ubuntu server running ?

As a side note, right now, my site works with the following configuration, but I'm willing to change if that helps my case, as I have root access to Ubuntu:

- Web site is configured with Kestrel behind Apache in proxy.
- I copied my code over to the Ubuntu server and publish to get the dlls.
- I created a service to run Kestrel

Comment: The publish wizard was designed only for IIS on Windows. Before Microsoft adds support for Linux or opens up the protocol for others to implement the support, you have to use whatever you found.

Comment: probably better to set up a build in VSTS to build and publish the site to your Ubuntu box